# Why was "Logical fallacy: X is bad, Y is worse, thus X is not bad" closed?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

[Logical fallacy: X is bad, Y is worse, thus X is not bad](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/352830/62591) was closed because:

> This question does not appear to be about English language and usage within the scope defined in the help center.

Yet, at the time of writing, it has 20 upvotes (I cannot see the downvotes, if any), and four answers totalling fifty upvotes. In addition, there are [158](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=Logical%20fallacy) results search for *logical fallacy* for 31 questions (the reset are answers -- thanks to [Helmar](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/users/184706/helmar) for point this out); many of those ([1](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16132/does-this-logical-fallacy-have-a-name?s=4%7C2.2035), [2](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/47577/word-for-logical-fallacy-of-including-a-debatable-proposition-in-a-list-of-truis?s=7%7C1.9353) for example) specifically ask to identify a logical fallacy. *Word choice and usage* is on topic. It's the [first](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) bullet point on the help and just what I am asking about. I can justify that it does not fall into the out of scope bullet points.

So, I cannot fathom why was it closed: **How can I tweak it so it gets re-opened?**

Comment: For what it's worth, your question's +20 is actually +20/-0.  :-)

Comment: @Hellion: Thanks. I could have looked at my reputation and worked it out as well but did not think of it at the time.

Comment: It's actually 31 hits, the rest are answers to those questions. Otherwise I agree I don't know why it's off-topic.

Comment: @Helmar Oh dear… Thank you!

Comment: It's an interesting question, but not really at it's base one of English (the same question would work in any language).

Answer (score 2):

I checked with the moderators on the [Philosophy Stack Exchange site](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/) about your question, and they said it’s on-topic there so I’ve emigrated it [thither](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/38375/logical-fallacy-x-is-bad-y-is-worse-thus-x-is-not-bad).

Answer (score -1):

I haven't asked its closers, but I can well imagine it was closed because it is not about English Language and Usage.  It should probably be on the [Philosophy site](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com) instead.

That said, the frequent obsession over logical fallacies is a mystery to many of us.

Comment: if I understand you right, looking for a word based on its definition is off topic?

Comment: @Sardathrion Looking for a word based on its definition is discouraged, but not always off topic. Please see the description of the single word request tag for the requirements that apply to any such question.